Understanding 物好きか余程のスキルポイント不足
In Konosuba chapter 3, Kazuma got told that he doesn't have enough points to acquire all beginner magic skills:

まあ確かにアレを覚えるのは物好きか余程のスキルポイント不足

I am not sure what nuance does 物好きか add in this sentence. Does 物好きか余程のスキルポイント不足 mean something like "not having enough skill points to the point that this skill can be acquired only by someone who is very devoted to beginner magic"?



Kazuma got told that he doesn't have enough points to acquire all beginner magic skills

I don't know the story well, but from the panels, I don't think he is told that. He is told that if there are people who learn those beginner skills, that must be because they don't have enough points [to learn more advanced skills].
I would imagine that the implication is that rational people would go straight to learning more advanced skills, and that it is a waste of time to learn those beginner skills (in the opinion of the speaker).
物好き is literally 'having a peculiar taste' but can mean something along the lines of "unwise" and "irrational", somewhat passive-aggressively.

Thank you. I think the root of my confusion is the meaning of か after 物好き. It seems to mean "or." He got told that those who acquire beginner skills are the ones with peculiar taste or not having enough points [for advanced skills].
